# Yii2 DataProvider

Tags: yii2, seo

Подскажите. Вывожу список товаров с пагинацией. Хочу добавить в `<head>` тег:

```
<link rel="prev" href="http://site.ru/categotia?page=2">
<link rel="next" href="http://site.ru/categotia?page=4">
```

Как мне узнать на какой странице сейчас нахожусь? И узнать есть ли следующая страница. И как сделать 301 редирект с страницы `http://site.ru/categotia?page=1` на `http://site.ru/categotia`

Comment: Вопрос решил. Всем спасибо

Comment: Выложите решение своего вопроса, поможете другим в будущем.